# diagonalization function

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

If we have a matrix `m` which is `n*n`, how can I do `mm=U^dagger m U` which is a transformation that put the `m`'s eigenvalues on the main diameter of a new matrix `mm`. the sorted of Norm[eigenvalues] is better (from larger to smaller).

```
m = {{2, 5, 1, 0}, {2, 0, -1, -2}, {2, 3, 4, -3}, {0, 1, -2, 2}};
```

as

```
mm = {{6.28, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2.8, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.30, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1.46}};
```

We can use of

```
temporary = Reverse[Sort@Eigenvalues[m] // N]
mm = ConstantArray[0, {4, 4}]
Do[If[i == j, mm[[i, j]] = temporary[[i]]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}];
```

I am sure that Mathematica has a function that generate the last result instead of the above code. But I don't know what is this function!?

Comment: So you need the eigenvectors ...

Comment: ...and to write a bit of code...

Comment: ... and may be take a look at `Eigensystem` ... give it a try in the documentation.

Comment: For example: `Do[If[i == j, mm[[i, j]] = temporary[[i]]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]` if we have `temporary = Reverse[Sort@Eigenvalues[m] // N]`

Comment: I know we can use of Eigenvectors and then create a matrix from those, but my question is not about finding `U`. My question is about a function which does this work.

Comment: The forum expectation is that a poster will try something and ask specific questions, rather than just ask for others to write up a function from scratch.

Comment: @Daniel, As you wanted me, I wrote a bit code in my mind, besides so much thanks of your comments, unfortunately I cannot understand meaning of your last comment. If possible, and if it is important please let me know to correct my question to be better.

Comment: As has been mentioned, `Eigensystem` is needed here. Then reorder by eigenvalues. The following code gives the conversion matrix along with the ordered eigenvalues.`{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[N[m]];
order = Reverse[Ordering[Abs[vals]]];
valsO = vals[[order]];
vecsO = vecs[[order]];` Note it is sorted by eigenvalue size (abs) since that's what was requested.

Comment: @Daniel, I think this is a misunderstanding. Your answer is which we have used for sorting eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but I was searching another thing. Please look at the Dr.belisarius's answer (which is below). His answer is exactly what I was searching and tend to know. So much thanks of your comments.

Comment: The post mentions sorting by eigenvalues and also by their norms. The post mentions wanted the sorted diagonal matrix and also the conversion to that matrix. This is more confusion than one wants to see in a question that, to all appearances, would be answered by checking documentation for `Eigenvalues` and `Sort`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
m = {{2, 5, 1, 0}, {2, 0, -1, -2}, {2, 3, 4, -3}, {0, 1, -2, 2}};
base[m_] := Transpose[SortBy[Eigenvectors[m] // N, Norm]]
diag[m_] := Chop[Inverse@#.m.#]&@base[m]
diag[m] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Besides so much thanks of you, but I wanted to know is there  a default function with this duty?

Comment: `SortBy[Transpose@Eigensystem@m // N, Norm[#[[2]]] &][[All, 
   1]] // DiagonalMatrix`